# PHP merge array is simular

Tags: php

How can I modify the below code so that it merges cell together that have the same data (in this case the same hex). At the moment it works with a max of 2 width.

```
    function generateArray($from, $until, $spread){
        $from = array(hexdec(substr($from,0,2)),hexdec(substr($from,2,2)),hexdec(substr($from,4,2)));
        $until = array(hexdec(substr($until,0,2)),hexdec(substr($until,2,2)),hexdec(substr($until,4,2)));
        $red=($until[0]-$from[0])/($spread-1);
        $green=($until[1]-$from[1])/($spread-1);
        $blue=($until[2]-$from[2])/($spread-1);

        for($i=0;$i<$spread;$i++){
            $newred=dechex($from[0]+round($i*$red));
            if(strlen($newred)<2) $newred="0".$newred;

            $newgreen=dechex($from[1]+round($i*$green));
            if(strlen($newgreen)<2) $newgreen="0".$newgreen;

            $newblue=dechex($from[2]+round($i*$blue));
            if(strlen($newblue)<2) $newblue="0".$newblue;

            // Check if current hex is same as previous
            if($i >= 1 && (isset($return[$i-1]) && $return[$i-1]['hex'] == "#".$newred.$newgreen.$newblue)){
                $return[$i-1]['width']++;
            } else {
                $return[$i] = array(
                        'hex' => "#".$newred.$newgreen.$newblue,
                        'width' => 1
                );
            }

        }

        return $return;
    }
```

Output:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td bgcolor='#ffffff' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#ffffff' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fefefe' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fefefe' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fdfdfd' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fdfdfd' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fcfcfc' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fcfcfc' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fbfbfb' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fbfbfb' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fafafa' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#fafafa' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#f9f9f9' width='2'></td>
<td bgcolor='#f9f9f9' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#f8f8f8' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#f6f6f6' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#f3f3f3' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#f1f1f1' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#eeeeee' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#ececec' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#eaeaea' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#e7e7e7' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#e5e5e5' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#e3e3e3' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#e0e0e0' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#dedede' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#dbdbdb' width='1'></td>
<td bgcolor='#d9d9d9' width='1'></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use an output-array:

```
$ret = array();
```

and every hex-code would be an index of your output array:

```
$ret[$HEX] = $width;
```

if your $HEX index always had been set, just increase your "width" value.

```
if(isset($ret[$HEX]))
{
    $ret[$HEX] ++;
}
else
{
    $ret[$HEX] = 1;
}
```

to display your table-thingy, use: foreach:

```
foreach(generateArr(...) as $hex => $width)
{
    echo sprintf
    (
        '<td bgcolor="#%s" width"%s">&nbsp;</td>',
        $hex,$width
    );
}
```